# how do I seperate hair texture from regular texture

Tags: texturing, particles, hair

I have a "Keentools FaceBuilder" head going with my face texture on it. I also have a simple hair particle system for my (scraggly) beard (picture 1). I have a simple "Principled BSDF" shader (For my face texture) and a "Principled Hair BSDF" shader (for my hair) mixed with a "Mix Shader" node and a "Hair Info" node plugged into the factor of the "Mix Shader" with the "Is Strand" as the output (picture 2). The result is to completely black out my face and only have the hair texture (picture 3). **Is this the right way to split the hair and regular textures, or am I doing it completely wrong?**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you want are 2 materials:

- one material for the skin (*Image Texture* and *Principled BSDF*)
- and one for the hair. For Cycles, you can use the *Principled Hair BSDF*. It works only in Cycles and you have to switch to Cycles to be able to add the node. To have a fallback for Eevee and the Material Preview mode you can add another node setup in the same material that is used for Eevee only.
  [image: output nodes for Eevee and cycles]

Just add another material slot for the head/emitter and create a material. After that, you can select it in the hair settings: *Particle Properties > Render > Material*

If you use Cycles make sure you have the settings for the *Hair Shape* correct (small values) else you will get very "fat" hair.